# Cipher built from GPU primitives

Tags: hash, encryption

Is it feasible to build a cipher (or hash) out of GPU or DSP primitives (e.g. big matrix multiplication, Fast Fourier Transform, big block SIMD, or hardware H.264/AVC codec)? Preferably those are slow to run on conventional CPU but a lot faster on GPUs and DSPs.

So if such a GPU or DSP-based cipher or hash is feasible, is there any examples or learning resources for a beginner?

Comment: **Yes.** Makes me think: what exactly are you asking? Currently, your question is answerable with a simple *Yes* or *No* and I’m not sure what other information to add to it since you don’t provide anything else to answer. Maybe you could edit your question to enhance it? In case of doubt, read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Perhaps you would like to ask whether such ciphers or hashes already exist?

Comment: Or alternatively, what GPU primitives are currently used in these hashes and why?